# Baking chicken in the oven

Tags: chicken

Can I bake small pieces of chicken in the oven on a metal bake sheet? Or would glassware be better?  When I say small, I mean 1/2 inch pieces

Comment: Personally I would go with (greased) metal. I find baking "wet" foods on glassware has a tendency to boil rather than roast.

Comment: When you say greased, would the olive oil I'm tossing the chicken in be enough?

Comment: Or could I put parchment paper down on the pan?

Comment: That really depends on your tray tbh; if you have a well seasoned tray then the oil that you tossed the chicken it should easily be enough. You'll have to learn how your tray behaves...

Answer (score 4):

I think you are better off sauting small pieces of chicken on the stove. Small pieces of chicken cook very quickly and can dry out in the oven.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can cook small pieces in the oven.  If you're cooking a whole panful, a greased metal pan would likely be best (or greased chicken on your metal pan, whichever).  When I'm cooking just a few pieces of something, one person's worth, I'll sometimes just pop them on the baking stone or even just on the rack - though your tolerance for such shortcuts may vary.

For such small pieces, they'll likely cook pretty quickly, so you might want to consider that when choosing how to cook them, though.  If you pan is large enough for them to be fairly spaced out, I would suggest preheating your oven well, and turning it off as soon as the chicken is placed inside - they will cook in residual heat, and the cooking will be both a bit slower (less likely to overshoot) and less direct (less likely to cook unevenly, say, burned on top).  Of course, if you're cooking enough to crowd the whole pan, you might want to adjust your cooking method suitably.